# Test assertion fails for Update

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a simple method that updates a picklist field in a before update action.

```
public static void updateRevStatus(List<Opportunity> filtered)
{
    for(Opportunity oppy: filtered)
    {
        oppy.Revenue_Status__c = 'Generated From Automation';
    }
}
```

In my test class I use @testSetup to create my Opportunity record so I can get it and update quickly. My problem is that the method does not update the field and when I do a system.assert it says the actual is null.

```
@isTest static void updateRevStatus()
{
    // Get the Opportunity record
    List<Opportunity> oppy = [SELECT Id, Revenue_status__c FROM Opportunity];

    // Send to hanmdler to do stuff
    OpportunityTriggerHandler.updateRevStatus(oppy);

    // Get the Opportunity record again
    Opportunity oppyQ = [SELECT Id, Revenue_status__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppy];
    System.assertEquals('Generated From Automation', oppyQ.Revenue_Status__c);
}
```

Is this the correct way to test this type of logic? Why would it not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you may call your handler, you never actually update the records. Normally the trigger would do this for you, but when you call a handler method from outside of a trigger context, no update will ever happen. The data in your query will be different than the data you provided to the handler.

If you want to write your test classes this way, check the data modified by the function, and not the data in the database.

```
@isTest static void updateRevStatus()
{
    List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, Revenue_status__c FROM Opportunity];

    OpportunityTriggerHandler.updateRevStatus(opps);

    for (Opportunity oppyQ:opps) {
        System.assertEquals('Generated From Automation', oppyQ.Revenue_Status__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You get my last vote for the day. :)

Answer (score 5):

No you are testing neither your trigger *nor* your service here.

**Service**

To test your service, assert on your input collection:

```
List<Opportunity> input = ...

Test.startTest();
    OpportunityService.updateRevStatus(input);
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(EXPECTED_COUNT, input.size,
    'Any time you assert within a loop, make sure you are looping over something!');
for (Opportunity record : input)
{
    system.assertEquals(EXPECTED_STATUS, record.Revenue_Status__c, '<your_message_here>');
}
```

**Trigger**

When you test your trigger, you need to actually perform a DML and then query back for the results.

```
List<Opportunity> records = ...

Test.startTest();
    insert records; // or update...
Test.stopTest();

List<Opportunity> insertedRecords = [/*query*/];
system.assertEquals(EXPECTED_COUNT, insertedRecords.size(),
    'All records should be successfully inserted');
for (Opportunity record : insertedRecords)
{
    // same assertion
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that instead of asserting that the value came out right I should asset that I passed the correct number of records through to the handler?

Comment: You pass your input into the service method (it should really be a separate layer from the handler). The service acts on your collection. Then you assert that all the records are still in it before checking that the correct data transformation took place.

Answer (score 2):

So you are testing a trigger helper method that likely runs in the `before` context so it doesn't actually call any DML statements on the record.

```
public static void updateRevStatus(List<Opportunity> filtered)
{
    for(Opportunity oppy: filtered)
    {
        oppy.Revenue_Status__c = 'Generated From Automation';
        //no update called
    }
}
```

Instead you should test by actually causing your trigger to fire:

```
@isTest static void updateRevStatus()
{
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    //... Setup state
    insert opp;
    Test.startTest();
       update opp;
    Test.stopTest();
    // Get the Opportunity record again
    opp = [SELECT Id, Revenue_status__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
    System.assertEquals('Generated From Automation', opp.Revenue_Status__c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving to the database so when you query the second time it is still showing a null value. If you want to cover updateRevStatus() you should be updating the Opportunitites and allow the trigger to call the method rather than calling it yourself in the test. Also, make sure to create your own test data rather than relying on existing org data.

```
@isTest static void updateRevStatus()
{
    // Create Test Data
    ...
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test',...);
    insert opp;

    Test.startTest();
    // Update the Opp to execute before update trigger
    ...
    update opp;
    Test.stopTest();

    // Get the Opportunity record again
    Opportunity oppyQ = [SELECT Id, Revenue_status__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = : opp.Id];
    System.assertEquals('Generated From Automation', oppyQ.Revenue_Status__c);
}
```